# Add event to button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

In this page there's a way to 
[dynamic add html (textbox,input button and radio elements with javascript](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/dynamic-add-textbox-input-button-radio-element-html-javascript.html)

my questioon is how can i add an event to the button, imagine that i only want create the button, not the textbox or the radio element.

**UPDATE**
I'm having problems here... I have tried some of the solutions provided but it causes me problems, let me try to explain...

im trying to open xml file, read it and create html object with the properties of the xml, so far so good, but if i try to add the event, xmlObj cames null any ideias??

i have this...

```
script = "function OnClientDragEnd(dock, args)" + 
                         "   {" + 
                                "var hidd = document.getElementById('" + HiddenField1.Value + "');" + 
                                "hidd.value = dock.get_id();" + 
                    //"alert(hidd.value);" + 
                                "var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');" + 
                                "xmlDoc.async = 'false';" + 
                                "xmlDoc.load('Config.xml');" + 
                                "xmlObj = xmlDoc.documentElement;" + 
                                "if (xmlObj.childNodes.length>0)" + 
                                "{" + 
                                "   for (var i = 0; i < xmlObj.childNodes.length; i++)" + 
                                "   {" + 
                                "       if (xmlObj.childNodes(i).getElementsByTagName('Id')[0].text == hidd.value){" + 
                                "           var txtTb2 = document.getElementById('" + TextBox4.ClientID + "');" + 
                                "           txtTb2.value = xmlObj.childNodes(i).getElementsByTagName('Titulo')[0].text;" + 
                                "           y = xmlObj.childNodes(i).getElementsByTagName('Titulo')[0].nextSibling;" + 
                                "           yy = xmlObj.childNodes(i).getElementsByTagName('Titulo')[0].previousSibling;" + 
                    //"           alert(y.nodeName);" + 
                                "           for(i=0;i<yy.text;i++){" + 
                                "               alert('aa');" + 
                                "               var tbox = document.createElement('input');" + 
                                "               tbox.setAttribute('type', 'text');" + 
                                "               tbox.setAttribute('value', y.text);" + 
                                "               tbox.setAttribute('name', 'name');" + 
                                "               var abcd = document.getElementById('spanObjDock');" + 
                                "               abcd.appendChild(tbox);" + 
                                "               var bt1 = document.createElement('input');" + 
                                "               bt1.setAttribute('name', 'mais');" + 
                                "               bt1.setAttribute('value', '+');" + 
                                "               bt1.setAttribute('type', 'button');" + 
                                "               bt1.onclick = function (){alert('Clicked!');};" + //--> this dont work 
                                //"               bt1.setAttribute('Click','addRadioButton()');" + //--> and this dont work 
                                "               abcd.appendChild(bt1);" + 
                                "               var bt2 = document.createElement('input');" + 
                                "               bt2.setAttribute('name', 'menos');" + 
                                "               bt2.setAttribute('value', '-');" + 
                                "               bt2.setAttribute('type', 'button');" + 
                                "               abcd.appendChild(bt2);" + 
                                "               var break1 = document.createElement('br');" + 
                                "               abcd.appendChild(break1);" + 
                                "               node = y;" + 
                                "               y=y.nextSibling;" + 
                                "           }" + 
                                "           break;    " +//<input type="button" onclick="" name"as" /> 
                                "       }" + 
                                "   }" + 
                                "}" + 
                            "}";//+
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply, use `addEventListener` method:

```
buttonRef.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("Blah blah...");
}, false);
```

(You'll have to Google for cross-browser solution. IE doesn't support `addEventListener`)

Where `buttonRef` is a reference to button. How can you get that reference? There's lots of ways to do that. You can use `document.getElementById()` or any other method from this "family".

Comment: It works! I have some difficulties, anything that i eventually added, i received error that xmlObj was null, but i restart VS2008 close some windows and it starts to work. thanks!!

Comment: Found this link that helped 

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM:element.addEventListener

Comment: IE 9 actually supports `addEventListener` [ref](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927637/addeventlistener-in-internet-explorer#6927800).

Answer (score 5):

```
var element = document.createElement("input");
element.onclick = function() {alert('Clicked!');};
```

Comment: jinx! darn, beat me by one second... shouldn't have put that extra example in!

Comment: Actually it seems the timestamp is exactly the same for both our posts. :D

Answer (score 3):

Probably the easiest cross-browser way is to set the event name as a property of the element:

```
Element.onclick = function () 
{
   // do something...
}
Element.onmouseup = function () 
{
   // do something else...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to attach the new event when creating the DOM element.

For example :

```
var e = document.createElement('input');
e.onclick = function()
            {
               alert('Test');
            };
```