# addEventListener in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, addeventlistener

What is the equivalent to the Element Object in Internet Explorer 9?

```
if (!Element.prototype.addEventListener) {
    Element.prototype.addEventListener = function() { .. } 
}
```

How does it works in Internet Explorer?

If there's a function equal to `addEventListener` and I don't know, explain please.

Any help would be appreciated. Feel free to suggest a completely different way of solving the problem.

Comment: Whether a browser implements a prototype inheritance scheme for its DOM objects is not relevant to whether it supports the W3C [EventTarget interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-EventTarget-addEventListener). If you wish to test for support, test it directly: `if(element.addEventListener) {/*supported*/} else {/*not supported*/}` is effective in all browsers and is independent of the implementation.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

`addEventListener` is the proper DOM method to use for attaching event handlers.

Internet Explorer (up to version 8) used an alternate `attachEvent` method.

Internet Explorer 9 supports the proper `addEventListener` method.

The following should be an attempt to write a cross-browser `addEvent` function.

```
function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
   if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
      elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
   else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
      elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
   }
   else { // No much to do
      elem["on"+evnt] = func;
   }
}
```

Comment: The last condition should also include `"on"+`.

Comment: For IE9 and addEventListener you need an HTML5 <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: @pcunite wish I could up vote that comment more. Very important point

Comment: Also since IE9 uses IE7 rendering mode in Compatibility view, only the attachEvent works.  So it is important to have this check instead of relying on addEventListener.

Answer (score 16):

John Resig, author of jQuery, submitted his version of cross-browser implementation of `addEvent` and `removeEvent` to circumvent compatibility issues with IE's improper or non-existent `addEventListener`.

```
function addEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
  if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
    obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
    obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}
    obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
  } else
    obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
}
function removeEvent( obj, type, fn ) {
  if ( obj.detachEvent ) {
    obj.detachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
    obj[type+fn] = null;
  } else
    obj.removeEventListener( type, fn, false );
}
```

Source: http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/

Comment: This code tries to bind callback fn to obj in addition to adding an event listener, but this is redundant because everyone using JS should already know about `this`.

Comment: You would've gotten more votes if you had introduced John Resig as the author of **jQuery**.

Comment: This implementation isn't complete. It's missing the useCapture parameter.

Answer (score 14):

I'm using this solution and works in IE8 or greater.

```
if (typeof Element.prototype.addEventListener === 'undefined') {
    Element.prototype.addEventListener = function (e, callback) {
      e = 'on' + e;
      return this.attachEvent(e, callback);
    };
  }
```

And then:

```
<button class="click-me">Say Hello</button>

<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('.click-me')[0].addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log('Hello');
  });
</script>
```

This will work both IE8 and Chrome, Firefox, etc.

Comment: I have problem with Element (type is undefined)

Comment: check your document type version, this should be html5 doctype

Answer (score 2):

As Delan said, you want to use a combination of addEventListener for newer versions, and attachEvent for older ones.

You'll find more information about event listeners on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener#Internet_Explorer). (Note there are some caveats with the value of 'this' in your listener).

You can also use a framework like [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to abstract the event handling altogether.

```
$("#someelementid").bind("click", function (event) {
   // etc... $(this) is whetver caused the event
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's something for those who like beautiful code.

```
function addEventListener(obj,evt,func){
    if ('addEventListener' in window){
        obj.addEventListener(evt,func, false);
    } else if ('attachEvent' in window){//IE
        obj.attachEvent('on'+evt,func);
    }
}
```

Shamelessly stolen from [Iframe-Resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer).

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` is supported from version 9 onwards; for older versions use the somewhat similar `attachEvent` function.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

I wrote a snippet that emulate the EventListener interface and the ie8 one, is callable even on plain objects:
https://github.com/antcolag/iEventListener/blob/master/iEventListener.js

OLD ANSWER

this is a way for emulate addEventListener or attachEvent on browsers that don't support one of those
hope will help

```
(function (w,d) {  // 
    var
        nc  = "", nu    = "", nr    = "", t,
        a   = "addEventListener",
        n   = a in w,
        c   = (nc = "Event")+(n?(nc+= "", "Listener") : (nc+="Listener","") ),
        u   = n?(nu = "attach", "add"):(nu = "add","attach"),
        r   = n?(nr = "detach","remove"):(nr = "remove","detach")
/*
 * the evtf function, when invoked, return "attach" or "detach" "Event" functions if we are on a new browser, otherwise add "add" or "remove" "EventListener"
 */
    function evtf(whoe){return function(evnt,func,capt){return this[whoe]((n?((t = evnt.split("on"))[1] || t[0]) : ("on"+evnt)),func, (!n && capt? (whoe.indexOf("detach") < 0 ? this.setCapture() : this.removeCapture() ) : capt  ))}}
    w[nu + nc] = Element.prototype[nu + nc] = document[nu + nc] = evtf(u+c) // (add | attach)Event[Listener]
    w[nr + nc] = Element.prototype[nr + nc] = document[nr + nc] = evtf(r+c) // (remove | detach)Event[Listener]

})(window, document)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use these polyfill https://github.com/WebReflection/ie8

```
<!--[if IE 8]><script
  src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ie8/0.2.6/ie8.js"
></script><![endif]-->
```