# Nested event handlers on IE

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I am successfully adding `dragover`, `dragleave` and `drop` event handlers from a `dragenter` triggered callback function.

IE11 won't add the tree event handlers though.
Any suggestions?

```
// Drag-and-drop initiation. 
    if (!isMobile() && window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        // Declare global variables.
        var dragStartsInside = false;
        
        // Initialize scripts.
        addEvent(window, "load", function () {
            for (var e=0; e < elementsArray.length; e++) {
                // Setup dnd listeners. 
                addEvent(elementsArray[e], "dragstart", function() {dragStartsInside = true; } ); 
                addEvent(elementsArray[e], "dragenter", dragEnter); 
                addEvent(elementsArray[e], "dragend", function() {dragStartsInside = false; } ); 
            }
        }); 
        
        // Drag and drop events. 
        function dragEnter(evt) { 
            cancelBubble(evt); 
            if (!dragStartsInside) {
                // Add "dragStartsInside"-dependent events. 
                addEvent(evt.target, "dragover", dragOver); 
                addEvent(evt.target, "dragleave", dragLeave); 
                addEvent(evt.target, "drop", drop); 
            }
            return cancelDefaultAction(evt);
        }
        
        function dragOver(evt) {
            cancelBubble(evt);
            ...
            return cancelDefaultAction(evt);
        }
        
        function drop(evt) {
            cancelBubble(evt);
            dragLeave(evt); 
            ...
            return cancelDefaultAction(evt);
        }
        
        function dragLeave(evt) {
            removeEvent(evt.target, "dragover", dragOver); 
            removeEvent(evt.target, "dragleave", dragLeave); 
            removeEvent(evt.target, "drop", drop); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [attachEvent Doesn't work in IE > 8.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20180046/attachevent-doesnt-work-in-ie-8-0)

Comment: _addEvent_ is custom: 

`function addEvent(element, eventType, callbackFunction) {
 if (element.addEventListener)
  element.addEventListener(eventType, callbackFunction, false);
 else if (element.attachEvent)
  element.attachEvent('on' + eventType, callbackFunction);
}`

Comment: Also _cancelBubble_ and _cancelDefaultAction_ are custom: 

`function cancelBubble(e) {
 var event = e ? e : window.event; 
 if (event.stopPropagation) event.stopPropagation(); 
 else if (event.cancelBubble!=null) event.cancelBubble = true; 
}`

`function cancelDefaultAction(e) {
 var event = e ? e : window.event; 
 if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault(); 
 event.returnValue = false; 
 return false;
}`