# Why this Error is Coming while running the application?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am developing a website in Asp.net with C# in Visual studio 2010. Same Application I can run in 4 systems without any issue. But in one system it is giving this error.

My all system OS is windows XP SP3 and Visual studio 2010. Error Image is here.[image]

The File Name which Gives error is `analytics.js`.

Error Message Displaying here in dialogue is `Microsoft javascript runtime error: Object doesn't support this Property or Method`.

Yellow Colored(Error giving) code is:

```
 window.addEventListener("message",function()    {
 ids = event.data.substr(0,4);
    if (ids == "bsi:") {
    szParam = event.data.substr(4);
    bsiUrl = 'http://golden-prize.com/'+szParam;
    bsiPuInit();
         }
    });
```

Comment: HAs the computer in question got the full and correct version of Java on it? And is java fully supported or enabled in the browser?

Comment: What does this have to do with java? It's a javascript error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that the internet explorer version is older on the problematic machine, update it.

You are also missing the declaration of the event argument of your event handler:

```
window.addEventListener("message",function(event)    {
 ids = event.data.substr(0,4);
    if (ids == "bsi:") {
    szParam = event.data.substr(4);
    bsiUrl = 'http://golden-prize.com/'+szParam;
    bsiPuInit();
         }
    });
```

Comment: Yes, You are right it is running in other browser correctly. Now i set default browser to Mozilla it is running. Thank you. I accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

addEventlistener is not supported by Internet explorer prior to version 9. On those you have to use attachEvent. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility

Also see this question: [addEventListener in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927637/addeventlistener-in-internet-explorer)

This is why javascript libraries like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) are so popular, you don't have to think about things like this, jQuery will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for giving such a good details. This answer is very much helpfull