# Get scroll direction without scrolling

Tags: javascript

How can I detect the scroll direction (mousewheel up/down) without scrolling the page?
My page wrapper has a height of 100%, so there is no content to scroll, but I need the scroll direction from the mousewheel.

Since Google Maps does the same (using the mousehweel for zoom without "scrolling" the page), I wonder how to achieve this.

Comment: Here are informations about how to do what you want : http://www.adomas.org/javascript-mouse-wheel/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are talking about the mouse wheel, you can use `addEventListener` on the window. `event.wheelDelta` will have a delta of `-120` or `120`, for scrolling down and up, respectively.:

```
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(e){
    wDelta = e.wheelDelta < 0 ? 'down' : 'up';
    console.log(wDelta);
});
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/4LyTS/)

Of course, you'll need to cater for different browsers. But i'll leave that up to you. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6927800/1612146)

Comment: Glad to have helped (:

Comment: Just what I seeking, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can add handler to `mousewheel` event with getting not only `event` object, but also wheel delta.

```
// Using jQuery library
$(function() {
    $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
       // delta > 0 scroll up 
       // delta < 0 scroll down
    });
});
```

Pure javascript:

```
document.onmousewheel = function(evt){
    console.log(evt) // take a look in your console at evt.wheelDeltaX, evt.wheelDeltaY
     //evt.wheelDeltaX is horizont scroll
     //evt.wheelDeltaY is vertical scroll
     //evt.wheelDelta is deltas x+y 

     // if evt.wheelDeltaY < 0 then scroll down, if >0 then scroll up
     // if evt.wheelDeltaX < 0 then scroll left, if >0 then scroll right
}
```

Comment: You may want to mention that you are using jQuery, since the OP didn't ask for it.

Answer (score 0):

check out jQuery MouseMove http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/
store the previous x y into variables and compare it with the current onces to determine the direction of the mouse pointer

Answer (score 0):

I modified Georges answer to work with modern browsers. The mousewheel event is obsolete and thus doesn't work anymore.

The following code snippet should work in all modern browsers:

```js
window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e){
    let wDelta = e.deltaY > 0 ? 'down' : 'up';
    console.log(wDelta);
});
```