# Javascript Tip Calculator

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a tip calculator in Javascript where the user should be able to type in the amount of the bill, push "calculate", and see both the tip and the total (which includes the bill and the tip).

I've been working at this for a while, but can't seem to make it work correctly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Tip Calculator</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
    </header>
    <form>
        Amount: $<input id="bill" type="text">
        <br>
        <button onclick="calc()">Calculate</button>
        <br>
        Tip: <span id="tip"></span>
        <br>
        Total: <span id="total"></span>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function calc() {
        var bill = document.getElementById('bill').value;
        var tip = bill * .15;
        var total = bill + tip;

        document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML= "$"+(tip).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "$"+(total).toFixed(2);         
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "can't seem to make it work correctly" doesn't help.  Describe in detail your problem.

Comment: Using a debug tool such as Firebug for Firefox can make it much easier to identify issues in your javascript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms are typically used to submit data to a server for various reasons. However, they have some benefits even when everything is being done on the same page (such as being able to press enter in any input and still have it submit without using extra code). What I did here was give it an `action` of the function you wanted to use and then changed your button to a standard `submit`.

There are various methods for taking a string and making it into a number, I used the simplest here: `Number()`. I used it on `bill` in order to make the `total_bill` display properly (instead of adding two strings together which just places them side by side). I changed `total` to `total_bill` for the variable because it is just not a good idea to name multiple things the same (e.g. the id and the variable). I missed the bill/bill, but I'll leave it as is because it does usually still work (like here).

Lastly, `toFixed()` takes a number and makes it a string. Which means you have to make sure it's a number and not already a string. This is why `Number()` was used again before outputting.

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Tip Calculator</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
    </header>
    <form action="javascript:void(calc())">
        Amount: $<input id="bill" type="text">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
        <br>
        Tip: <span id="tip"></span>
        <br>
        Total: <span id="total"></span>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function calc() {
        var bill = Number(document.getElementById('bill').value);
        var tip = bill * .15;
        var total_bill = bill + tip;

        document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML= "$"+Number(tip).toFixed(2);
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "$"+Number(total_bill).toFixed(2);         
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly! I really appreciate you taking the time to explain the modified code. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3221658 Accept whatever, I have plenty of rep, but PLEASE consider the best practices I show you and explain in my answer. Please. I spent a lot of time preparing that for you.

Comment: ^ I can't agree enough. Please don't use inline JS. Use an MVC approach and you'll be set

Comment: @m59 I like to fix a person's code while keeping as true to what they original had as possible. You are telling them to use parseInt with a specified base 10...this is money, which has hundredths places. Wutrudoin?

Comment: @Rhyono Good point - I updated. As for the philosophy - the majority of code I see coming from the web world is rife with awful practices. It is impossible for me to see SO posts that also have bad practices all over them and not think it's a related issue. I think it's therefore very important that we evangelize the best practices as often and as passionately as we can. Just think how much identity theft could have been prevented if people saw a desperate please about prepared statements and listened to it.

Comment: Please don't encourage javascript: urls, nor inline JS.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few problems. You need the event passed by the click function so that you can stop the form from submitting traditionally, which causes a page refresh. The best practice is to attach the click handler with javascript. You also need to convert the string value of the input into an actual number so that it can be used for addition.

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/ahOmEgA/5/edit)**

```
// get element references - no need to keep repeating this in the function
var myBtn = document.getElementById('my-button');
var tipElem = document.getElementById("tip");
var totalElem = document.getElementById("total");

//attach click event listener
myBtn.addEventListener('click', calc);

//the event object is passed to this automatically - I'm assigning it to "e"
function calc(e) {
  //prevent the default action - form submit / page refresh
  e.preventDefault();
  var input = document.getElementById('bill');
  //convert string value to Number
  var bill = parseFloat(input.value);
  var tip = bill * 0.15;
  var total = bill + tip;

  //textContent is better than innerHTML for setting text
  tipElem.textContent = "$"+(tip).toFixed(2);
  totalElem.textContent = "$"+(total).toFixed(2);  
}
```

**Here is the markup I recommend:**

```
<form>
  <p>Amount: $<input id="bill" type="number"></p>
  <button id="my-button">Calculate</button>
  <p>Tip: <span id="tip"></span></p>
  <p>Total: <span id="total"></span></p>
</form>
```

`<br>` should not be used for layout. Instead, you can use `display: block` on the elements that should go to a new line. Many elements do this by default, such a `<p>`. I also changed the input type to `number` because that that seems more appropriate here.

Unfortunately, some people are going to suggest and argue that inline js (that's any kind of javascript in your html, like `onclick`) is ok to use. It isn't. I hope you will read some of these results: **[Why is inline JS bad?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)**

Comment: This example will be broken in older versions of IE. If you are messing with event listeners, you need to consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927637/addeventlistener-in-internet-explorer (or just use a lib that does this correctly).

Comment: @user1389596 It's worth asking yourself though "do users of old versions of IE (or current versions) deserve code to work for them?"

Comment: @user1389596 the important thing is to follow the professionally accepted standards first and implement backwards compatible solutions, not to disregard best practices altogether just because they may need to be shimmed. My aim in answering questions is to promote a world of better developers, not lazy ones with high SO reputation.

Comment: Arguing for support in old IE is just a bit silly. It leads to less maintainable code, not to mention having an actual cost associated with it, for a very small number of users. This is a good answer.

Comment: A third of the planet is probably running Windows XP, and the corporate world is also behind in IE versions.  What needs to be supported is not always up to the developer.

Comment: @phenomnomnominal, personally I find the old-school method a bit more maintainable.  It follows the ASP.net model. It's the same number of lines of code to do it either way.  The advantage of explicit handlers is you can inspect the element and see the event binding instantly.  If you've ever had to hunt for an event listener in a large project, you'll start to question the benefit of extreme code decoupling.   Especially if you don't even know to what/how it's been attached... it's not fun.   My $.02  :)

Answer (score 1):

Try a standard input button

```
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate">
```

Also, the toFixed() method doesn't necessarily exist on the var.  In testing in Chrome, it will work however if you explicitly cast to number

```
    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML= "$"+(new Number(tip)).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "$"+(new Number(total)).toFixed(2);
```

Comment: Sad. Upvotes for inline javascript. This is terrible practice and should never be used or recommended. Also, if you want a button, use a button.

Comment: Button doesn't work in older browsers.  Inline js is not terrible practice as long as it's sparse.  This is the same practice used in ASP.net.  Otherwise, I dislike hunting through thousands of lines of external javascript files just to find an event binding.

Comment: Believe what you will, but "sparse" is no excuse. It's ok to use it to test something really quickly - that's it.

Comment: You really shouldn't advocate inline JS

Comment: I agree that inlining js is not a good idea.  But the "best practice" advice that goes for extreme decoupling is a bit overboard.  The code in his example is perfectly readible.  I'd sooner suggest using jquery than mess with event binders without the lib. But that opens up another can of worms.

Comment: event binding is quite simple. @m59 has an answer that isn't difficult to read at all. And, it's not overhead in the slightest to use a good practice for even the smallest of tasks

Comment: The only thing of course is that example is completely broken in older versions of IE ... :)  I don't understand a best practice that doesn't work 100% of the time.

Comment: Oh, and btw, the fact that you'd advocate a whole library of JavaScript in leu of MCV scripting scares me

Comment: If you are messing with event listeners and want cross browser support, you need to do this differently or rely on a lib.  The example provided is broken in older versions of IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
function calc() {
    var bill = $("#bill").value;
    var tip = bill * .15;
    var total = bill + tip;

    document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML= "$"+(tip).toFixed(2);
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "$"+(total).toFixed(2);    

}
```

Also try to create **JSFIDDLE** for you to create some demo.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your form is being submitted hence it is losing values. There're many way to avoid this - one - define your form as

   `<form onsubmit="return false">`
2. Your total won't calculate because bill is read as string. One way to force it into number is multiply by 1, so total will be

   `var total = bill*1 + tip;`

Here's working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5GQZ8/

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Tip Calculator</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <header>
        <h1>Tip Calculator</h1>
    </header>
    <form>
        Amount: $<input id="bill" type="text">
        <br>
        <a onclick="calc()">Calculate</a>
        <br>
        Tip: <span id="tip"></span>
        <br>
        Total: <span id="total"></span>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    function calc() {
        var bill = document.getElementById('bill').value;
        var tip = bill * .15;
        var btotal = bill + tip;

        document.getElementById("tip").innerHTML= "$"+Number(tip);
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML= "$"+Number(btotal);
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your answer actually doesn't fix the majority of the problems. You may want to test code prior to posting it in the future.