# Switch to different button on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want code to switch the buttons. If I pressed button1 first time, it must show button2 and vice versa.

```
<input type="submit" value="asc" name="button1" id="but1">

<input type="submit" value="desc" name="button2" id="but3">
```

Comment: You are using `type="submit"` which will submit form. What exactly you want to acheive.

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Tried with javascript .hide().

Comment: I want to change buttons for call acending and descinding query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution **without** the need for JQuery would be this one:

```
<input type="button" value="asc" name="button1" id="but1" onClick="document.getElementById('but3').style.display='';this.style.display='none';">

<input type="button" value="desc" name="button2" id="but3" style="display:none;" onClick="document.getElementById('but1').style.display='';this.style.display='none';">
```

You can also do it this way if you want to use the visibility:

```
<input type="button" value="asc" name="button1" id="but1" onClick="document.getElementById('but3').style.visibility='visible';this.style.visibility='hidden';">

<input type="button" value="desc" name="button2" id="but3" style="visibility:hidden;" onClick="document.getElementById('but1').style.visibility='visible';this.style.visibility='hidden';">
```

Using visibility preserves the buttons position. I changed the type from submit to button just out of demonstration reasons.

You can look at both JSFIDDLE demos of these solutions [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qp7Ju/) and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5T7nm/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you can use:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().siblings('input[type="submit"]').show();   
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u5Fwt/)**

Comment: Thank you this is what i want but it submit's form and reset to orignal button i don't understand how to do.
i want to display asc and desc list on same button click.

Comment: I don't get what you means. Could you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
   var valueOfButton = $(this).val();
   if(valueOfButton == 'asc')
     {
         $('input[value="asc"]').show();
       $('input[value="desc"]').hide();
     }
     else
    {  
         $('input[value="desc"]').show();
         $('input[value="asc"]').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following functions:

- `$(element)click(callback)` will handle the click of the `element`
- `$(element).show()` will show the `element`
- `$(element).hide()` will hide the `element`

so a semple code is:

```
//first hidden the second button
$('#but3').css('display','none')

// handle click of first button
$('#but1').click(function(){
    $(this).hide()
    $('#but3').show()
});

// handle click of second button
$('#but3').click(function(){
    $(this).hide()
    $('#but1').show()
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/L7zux/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('but1').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('but1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('but3').style.visibility = 'visible'; }, false);

document.getElementById('but3').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('but3').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('but1').style.visibility = 'visible'; }, false);
```

If you want to hide button and its placeholder completely, use `style.display = 'none'` and `style.display = 'block'`. If you put both buttons in `div` container with default `static` positioning, then both buttons will appear at the same position in container.

Comment: One of question tags is `jQuery`, Why use pure JS ?!!

Comment: In IE 9 and above it works, in older IE should use attachEvent with `on` prefix to event name, but that's [different question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927637/addeventlistener-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use `.toggle()` in jQuery

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
   $('input[type="submit"]').toggle();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5Fwt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting your .toggle-radio-switch elements are siblings. Remove .parent() from your code. It isn't needed since .radio-switch-slider is contained directly in .toggle-radio-switch

$(this).find('.radio-switch-slider')

Answer (score 0):

By default when page will load put following code so that your second button will be hide.

`$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#but3').hide();
});`

After that Put code that were

`$('input[type="submit"]').click(function() {
    $(this).hide().siblings('input[type="submit"]').show();

});`