# Make JavaScript specific code work in IE7

Tags: javascript, function

This code works in modern browsers - but is not working in the IE7. Can someone help me where the problem lies:

```
function makePay() {
            var obj = {
                            'product' : 'speakers',
                            'paid' : 300,
                            'toBePaid' : 560,
                            'paymentsLeft' : 3,
            }              

            return (obj.toBePaid - obj.paid) / obj.paymentsLeft;
}

var btn = document.getElementById("result");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
            alert(makePay());
}, false);
```

Comment: Stop supporting IE7, and even IE8, problem solved !

Comment: What's this boom of asking about [legacy IE eventhandling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: at  property 'paymentsLeft' of obj there is a semikolon.

Comment: We handle IE7 at work because many of our clients in the government are forced to use it. So handling legacy is a moot point for some people. Or it's a school project requirement.

Comment: @adeneo Well, nobody supports old IE versions voluntarily. So “stop supporting IE 7” is not very helpful here :-)

Comment: try this: btn.onclick = function(){}

Answer (score 2):

The reason for IE 7 failing is the `addEventListener` method.

IE versions older than 9 have their own, proprietary method for attaching event handlers. You’ll need to check if `addEventListener` is supported and if it’s not the case, check for `attachEvent` and use this instead.

Example (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6927800/1387396):

```
function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
   if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
      elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
   else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
      elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
   }
   else { // No much to do
      elem[evnt] = func;
   }
}
```

Good luck! I feel with you.