# Try { ... } catch { ... } on addEventListener

Tags: javascript

How can I add an try catch in a addEventListener? Is there any way?

I need to use the try catch at addEventListener or attachEvent not in the inner function

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
 X();
    });


    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function () {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            X();
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: Why you need try-catch? And why not use it?

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting.

Comment: One person does it, others follow… Edit your question (add or delete a space somewhere), it will allow people to change their vote.

Comment: Some browsers are launching exceptions and we believe that it may be caused by this attachEvent or addEventListener at the attach event moment.

Comment: We need to use the try catch at addEventListener or attachEvent not in the inner function!

Comment: I'll write it here again - **WHY** ?! The only reason would be if `document` is not present... well - **CHECK IT**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
      try {
          x();
      } catch (e) {
          alert(e.message);
      }
  });


  document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function () {
      if (document.readyState === "complete") {
          try {
              x();
          } catch (e) {
              alert(e.message);
          }
      }
  });
```

If you are facing issue with event registration due to different browser capabilities use below code

```
if (document.addEventListener){  
  document.addEventListener(...);
} else if (document.attachEvent){  
  document.attachEvent(...);  
}
```

More generalized way

```
    function addEvent(evnt, elem, func) {
   if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM
      elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
   else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
      elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
   }
   else { // No much to do
      elem[evnt] = func;
   }
}
```

Comment: Working js  : https://jsfiddle.net/mj8aLkgh/

Comment: We need to use the try catch at addEventListener or attachEvent not in the inner function

Comment: check updated answer .  for generalize code you can refer following link 

http://stackoverflow.com/a/6927800/3264939

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add it like

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  try{
      X();
  }
  catch(e){
   //How you want to handle it
  }
});
```

Comment: We need to use the try catch at addEventListener or attachEvent not in the inner function

Comment: Why so?! Why in this world you would need to try-catch on adding an event listener? It's as simple as `if (document) { document.addEventListener`....

Comment: Because we use an softphone linked into our software by an java script function, and this addEventListener are throwing excepetions, and we believe that it may caused by an crossed injection, and the only way to confirm or discard this idea is by adding an try catch

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
try
{
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) { 
        X();
    });
}
catch(e) 
{ 
    alert('Couldnt create event listener.'); 
}
```

There is another example at the botton of this page:

http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/handleevent