# jquery addEventListener issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am using jquery(V2.1.3) in my project. sometimes my page is getting broken and throws me an error in jquery framework file in IE(9 and above) browser alone.

The error is from the below line,

Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'

```
n.ready.promise = function(b) {
    return H || (H = n.Deferred(), "complete" === l.readyState ? setTimeout(n.ready) : (l.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", I, !1), 
    a.addEventListener("load", I, !1))), H.promise(b);
},
```

Please provide me a solution to overcome this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [addEventListener in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927637/addeventlistener-in-internet-explorer)

Comment: Which line in your code throws this error?

Comment: it throws me error exactly at the 2nd line of the code above. Also, i have used meta tag for IE rendering <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">, is this causing issue?