# When I navigate from one page to another page in angular application I'm facing the following below error

Tags: angular

> Error: eventTask 'undefined.addEventListener:message': can not transition to 'running', expecting state 'scheduled', was 'notScheduled'

**I'm facing This issue only in IE11 and it works fine in other browsers**

```
<div *ngIf="!hasAccount" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
    <a routerLink="/login" class="loginBtn btn btn-default btn-raised" [ngClass]="{disabled: loading}">
        Login
    </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: I attach the below link for your reference [link](http://npmci.syncfusion.com/production/angular/demos/#/material/button/split-button) .  inspect the page and in console the error reflects

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: ` <div *ngIf="!hasAccount" class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <a routerLink="/login" class="loginBtn btn btn-default btn-raised" [ngClass]="{disabled: loading}">Login</a>
    </div>`

Comment: ** This works in all browsers except IE11 under windows 10. In IE11 the login page does not open and we get this error message from zone.ts on the console:**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927637/addeventlistener-in-internet-explorer

Comment: **Can you please explain in detail that how it (link) relate to my question?**

Comment: undefined.addEventListener:message you are using addEventListener to get event i think