# Cannot set property 'onclick' of null before document.write the element

Tags: javascript

What am I doing wrong? If this is a duplicated question, please redirect me to the correct question because I can't find anything about it.

It is that simple:

I get this error:
"**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null**"

In this hyper-mega-ultra-easy piece of code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.write('<input id="a" type="button" value="This is a button :)">');
  document.getElementById("a").onclick = alert("a");
}
```

How can this even be possible?
Regards.

Comment: Should work, but don't use document.write. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199949/add-event-to-button-with-javascript

Comment: Run the snippet. There is no such error.

Comment: That works, at least in the above snippet. When assign to `onclick` like that, it fires the `alert` when assigned. Instead wrap it in a function, e.g. `document.getElementById("a").onclick = function() { alert("a") };`

Comment: Also check out the note at the top of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write).

Answer (score 0):

Putting the code to run after the button is click into a function will make Javascript "connect" that function to the action from the user.

```js
window.onload = function() {
       document.write('<input id="a" type="button" value="This is a button :)">');
       document.getElementById("a").onclick = function() {
          alert("a");
       };
    }
```

Otherwise, instead of creating a new function, you can use another one already defined in your code but setting the onclick event = to the function without the parenthesis as shown below.

```js
function whenYouClick() {
 alert("a");
}

window.onload = function() {
document.write('<input id="a" type="button" value="This is a button :)">');
document.getElementById("a").onclick = whenYouClick;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of your code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.write('<input id="a" type="button" value="This is a button :)">');
  document.getElementById("a").onclick = alert("a");
}
```

You can use:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.write('<input id="a" type="button" value="This is a button :)">');
  document.getElementById('a').setAttribute('onclick','alert(0)');
}
```

Comment: Maybe the most absurd question I've ever seen and I'm in it :)